How to Get imgURI of Hidden ApexCharts or Alternative Chart Libraries that Support Hidden Charts?
I'm currently working with ApexCharts in a web application, and I need to generate an image URI (imgURI) of a chart. However, the chart is inside a div with opacity: 0 (or sometimes display: none). When trying to use the chart.dataURI() method, the resulting image is either blank or not as expected because the chart is not visible.
My questions are:

Is there a way to generate a valid imgURI from an ApexChart that is inside a hidden or invisible div (with opacity: 0 or display: none)?

If this isn't possible with ApexCharts, are there any other JavaScript charting libraries that allow for generating an imgURI of a chart even if the chart is not visible on the page?


What I've Tried:

Temporarily making the chart visible by changing the opacity or display properties, capturing the imgURI, and then hiding it again. While this works, it's a bit hacky and not ideal for my use case.

Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
